# How to send bcc email via `exim -t`? ["sendmail look alike" mode]

Tags: go, centos, exim, gomail

I'm using golang to send email with exim via following method

```
const sendmail = "/usr/sbin/exim"

func submitMail(m *gomail.Message) (err error) {
    cmd := exec.Command(sendmail, "-t")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

    pw, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    var errs [3]error
    _, errs[0] = m.WriteTo(pw)
    errs[1] = pw.Close()
    errs[2] = cmd.Wait()
    for _, err = range errs {
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
    }
    return
}
```

[as Answered on here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35521846/5806017)

The problem is that Exim removes Bcc with *-t*

> If Exim is called with the -t option, to take recipient addresses from
>   a message's headers, it removes any Bcc: header that may exist (after
>   extracting its addresses), unless the message has no To: or Cc:
>   header, in which case a Bcc: header with no addresses is left in the
>   message, in accordance with RFC 822. If -t is not present on the
>   command line, any existing Bcc: header is not removed.
>
> If Exim is called to receive a message with the recipient addresses
>   given on the command line, and there is no Bcc:, To:, or Cc: header in
>   the message, it normally adds a To: header, listing the recipients.
>   Some mailing list software is known to submit messages in this way,
>   and in this case the creation of a To: header is not what is wanted.
>   If the always_bcc option is set, Exim adds an empty Bcc: header
>   instead in this circumstance.

[found in Spec here](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-3.20/doc/html/spec_49.html#SEC832)

Comment: Why do you need the `-t` flag, why not simply remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Sendmail look alike" mode with`-t` removes `Bcc:` headers **after processing them**.
In `-t` mode `Bcc:` headers content will be appended to the (SMTP) recipients list **BUT** recipients will not see/receive `Bcc:` headers.

*Style guide suggestion:* **IF** you use another SMTP/MTA soft (e.g. Exim) in "sendmail look alike" (command line comparability mode) **THEN** use sendmail program/binary provided by them.
`const sendmail = "/usr/sbin/sendmail"`

Comment: I'm not receiving any mail to bcc email addresses maybe problem is in golang code

Comment: Yes the problem is in go code `_, errs[0] = m.WriteTo(pw)` is not sending bcc to exim