# Send emails in go through Exim (without smtp)?

Tags: go, exim, gomail

I'm currently using "gopkg.in/gomail.v2" to send email with following  [code found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35521846/5806017)

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"

    "gopkg.in/gomail.v2"
)

func main() {
    m := gomail.NewMessage()

    m.SetHeader("From", "me@example.com")
    m.SetHeader("To", "you@example.com")

    m.SetAddressHeader("Bcc", "youbcc@example.com", "Bcc Email")

    m.SetHeader("Bcc", "anotherbcc@example.com", "yetbcc@example.com")

    m.SetHeader("Reply-To", "me@example.com")
    m.SetHeader("Subject", "Subject is to gomail to be discussed")
    body := `Why is bcc not getting populated`
    m.SetBody("text/html", body)

    sendMailViaExim(m)

}
func sendMailViaExim(m *gomail.Message) (err error) {
    cmd := exec.Command("/usr/sbin/exim", "-t")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

    pw, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    var errs [3]error
    _, errs[0] = m.WriteTo(pw)
    errs[1] = pw.Close()
    errs[2] = cmd.Wait()
    for _, err = range errs {
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
    }
    return
}
```

The Above code **doesn't send to Bcc** emails;

So I logged the info that was being passed to `exim -t` via following code:

> buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
>
> m.WriteTo(buf) //should write entire msg with bcc?
>
> fmt.Println(buf.String())

and the console logged :

```
$ go run main.go
Mime-Version: 1.0
Date: Mon, 23 Apr 2018 11:15:54 +0530
To: you@example.com
Reply-To: me@example.com
Subject: Subject is to gomail to be discussed
From: me@example.com
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Why is bcc not getting populated
```

bcc is not getting to the `exim -t` How do I achieve that without using smtp.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's [this](https://github.com/go-gomail/gomail/commit/8de74d4f48c5aa343703bb1c7376d2aed0f9c258) (and [here](https://github.com/go-gomail/gomail/blob/81ebce5c23dfd25c6c67194b37d3dd3f338c98b1/CHANGELOG.md#L14) is the changelog entry for it).

Still, the logic fixed by the commit above should only apply to actually
*sending* messages—that is, when the package actually speaks with an SMTP
server (because, naturally, `Bcc` should not be forwarded past the first MTA processing the message (maybe even the first MDA—I'm lazy to read the RFC)).

The commit being discussed refers to
[this part of a relevant RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.3) which actually offers three different ways to handle `Bcc` header
fields.
So I have no idea whether to actually blame the package author for
this change or not.

Yet still, [this](https://github.com/go-gomail/gomail/blob/81ebce5c23dfd25c6c67194b37d3dd3f338c98b1/writeto.go#L244) looks like stripping the `Bcc` header away even for the `Message.WriteTo`
method, which, IMO, is a mistake.
The reason I think this is a mistake is as follows:

- When the package sends a message via SMTP it works as an MTA
  or an MDA and should obey the rules defined by the relevant RFCs for these
  types of mail agents.
- When it merely streams the message to an MDA (Exim in your case),
  it works as a pure client, and *processing* of the `Bcc` header fields
  is clearly not its business—it rather should be delegated to the first
  "real" mail processing agent.

The only relevant issue/pull-request I was able to find is
[this](https://github.com/go-gomail/gomail/pull/34) but it looks like the
code was highly refactored after its inclusion so I have no idea
whether it introduced what I supposed is a bug or not.

See also [this](https://github.com/go-gomail/gomail/issues/19).

**TL;DR**

I would file an issue in the package's bug tracker.

(If you will do that, please link it there; thanks.)

Comment: JFTR [the RFC on MDAs](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6409) contains no mention of the `Bcc` header field so I think it's purely an MTA thing.

Comment: so maybe any other library ? or should I loop the contacts (will it be spam/ junk?)

Comment: If you opt to talk to a locally running Exim instance via its SMTP or main submission (587) port, the problem goes away completely as you're free to issue any (sane) number of the `RCPT TO` SMTP commands during the single message submission session. Looks like making yourself a bit more aware about how e-mail works would not hurt you.

Comment: BTW, have you filed an issue with gomail?

Comment: To make my previous commit more clear, I *think* that's exactly what `gomail` does with the contents of the `Bcc` header field when it's present *and when* it's talking to an MTA/MDA via the SMTP protocol (as opposed to passing the message to the stdin of `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t` or the like): it takes all the addresses from the `Bcc` field and generates an `RCPT TO` command for each of them.

Comment: I've opened a issue on gomail repo https://github.com/go-gomail/gomail/issues/115 . How do I **opt to talk to a locally running Exim instance via its SMTP** I've tried `d := gomail.NewDialer("localhost", 587, "", "")` with error ___panic: gomail: could not send email 1: 550 Verification failed for <fromemail@myexampledomain.in>
Unrouteable address
Sender verify failed___  while using `d.TLSConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}`

Comment: Or should I custom implement `gomsg.WriteTo()` that sends data to `exim -t` ?

Comment: That `550 Verification failed for … Unrouteable address Sender verify failed` (may) have nothing to do with TLS. It means Exim failed to verify your `From` address *for some reason.* What exactly reason depends on how Exim is configured. You might get a hunch on this by enabling debugging output for Exim, retry mail submission and studying Exim log afterwards. All in all, this is outside of the scope of this discussion. As I've already suggested elsewhere, try asking about configuring Exim over there at https://superuser.com

Comment: Thank you for your time; I've asked it on SuperUser as you have advised : https://superuser.com/q/1316842/555998

Answer (score -2):

The problem is caused by the `-t` option you pass to exim. From [the docs](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-message_processing.html):

> ### 7. The Bcc: header line
>
> If Exim is called with the **-t** option, to take recipient addresses from
>   a message’s header, it removes any *Bcc:* header line that may exist
>   (after extracting its addresses). If **-t** is not present on the command
>   line, any existing *Bcc:* is not removed.

.